# How to update the title of appcompat toolbar from outside the activity class?

Tags: android

its a stupid question, but how can i reset toolbar title form another class. Not from MainActivity?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Toolbar toolbar;

 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

And i want to change title from TabAdapter.class. How can i do it?When i'm trying to do it i'm getting a nullpointerexception.

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:

                return MainFragment.getInstance();
            case 1:
                main.toolbar.setTitle("hello world");
                return SearchFragment.getInstance();


        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does your code even work? Because you are not supposed to instantiate an Activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your SearchFragment in onResume() set the title using getActivity():

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
((Toolbar) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
                    .setTitle("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By  `MainActivity main = new MainActivity();` this line you are creating a new object of activity that cant be used to update current.

So.

You can set the toolbar title by passing the current activity reference to the adapter.
After creating the adpater call the mathod to set the activity reference and do this in following way.

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private AppCompatActivity activity;

        public void setActivity(AppCompatActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    //here you can change title of toolbar


                    return MainFragment.getInstance();
                case 1:
                    //main.toolbar.setTitle("hello world");
                     updateToolbarTitle("Hello World");
                    return SearchFragment.getInstance();


            }
            return null;

        private void updateToolbarTitle(String title) {
            activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `MainActivity` pass the reference of activity to the adapter like this

```
TabAdapter adapter  = new TabAdapter(/*Your params here*/);
adapter.setActivity(this);
```

Comment: There is no chance of null pointer here. There must be some another issue. Try to track in which line you are getting that exception

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to initialise `MainActivity` in your `TabAdapter` class.

You should access the toolbar from your fragment and change it there. Here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return mToolbar;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // initialisation logic
        mToolbar = ... // get toolbar from layout
    }
}

public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onResume() {
        // get the hosting activity
        final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        // get it's toolbar
        final Toolbar toolbar = activity.getToolbar();
        // set the title
        toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better use  this.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mAdapter.getPageTitle(position));  
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

And in your FragmentPagerAdapter

```
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return title; //title for that position
  }
```